# Where are the default hardware button (ie. volume increase, screen brightness, play/stop music) scripts

Tags: scripts, acpi, events, media-buttons

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my Thinkpad x220t and was pleasantly surprised to find that the tablet button for rotating the screen works out of box. However, while it does rotate the screen it does not perform the commands to rotate the screen's pen input. In short, I am interesting in adjusting whatever script is being called here to call my own screen rotation script.

I looked in /etc/acpi and found nothing, and don't really know where to go from there. Does anybody know where to find the default scripts that listen to these hardware events?